# 2 file descriptors for the same file

Tags: c, unix, file-descriptor

I have a file descriptor >0 for a file that is already opened.
I want to add a second file descriptor to that file. I know this is possible if I open the file with the second file descriptor again but the problem is that in that point of my code I don't know the name of the file.

So I was wondering if I can just do that:
fd2 = fd1;

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't understand well the manual. If I do lseek for oldfd to change its position to the file, will the newfd also go to the same position? Is there any way I can have the file descriptors in different places in the file and do different tasks with each one?

Comment: Ok then thank you again

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude time to delete my comments then!

Comment: @pilcrow And +1 on your good answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may duplicate the file descriptor, returning a new, distinct handle to the same open file description, with either [`dup`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)

```
#include <unistd.h>
int fd2 = dup(fd1);
```

or with [`fcntl`/`F_DUPFD`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)

```
#include <fcntl.h>
int fd2 = fcntl(fd1, F_DUFPD, 0); // consider F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC !
```

Because *fd2* and *fd1* now refer to the [*same open file description*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/195057/7703), they "share" certain attributes of the underlying open file description:

- status flags (nonblocking, append-only, etc.)
- access mode (read-only, read-write, write-only)
- file position (reading/seeking on one will be reflected in the other)
- record locks (as with POSIX [`struct flock`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) locks)

If you change one of the above on *fd2*, that change will be visible in *fd1* since, again, both refer to the same underlying I/O construct.  The same thing happens when file descriptors are duplicated across processes ("inherited").

The descriptors themselves have only one interesting attribute of their own, FD_CLOEXEC, which controls whether or not the descriptor will be preserved (inherited) across an `execve` call.  This may differ for each descriptor.